# TypeScript: How to import a type only if it is defined in the other file

Tags: typescript

I have a set of files (*web components*). Some of those files define an optional type (it is in fact an interface with type definitions of the `event.detail` property for every custom event the component triggers, but let's for simplicity call it `OptionalType`).

There is another set of files, which are *generated* automatically. Each of those file corresponds to one web component and provides Preact types for that component.

I am looking for a way to conditionally define some of the types in the second, generated set of files, based on whether the original web component file exported `OptionalType` or not.

To give you a simplified example, this code could be in a component file:

```
export interface OptionalType {
  name: string
}
```

I figured initially that I could `import * as all`  and then to check if `all['OptionalType']` (or `typeof all['OptionalType']`, or `all.OptionalType`) exists. This is how I intend to use that type in the generated file:

```
import * as all from "./my-component"

type OptionalType = typeof all extends {
  OptionalType: unknown
}
  ? typeof all["OptionalType"]
  : never

// Do something with OptionalType
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. In JS `all` would be an object holding all the exports as properties. But in TS it is what seems to be a namespace. And I have no idea how to deal with those.

If I try to define those types inline for testing purposes, everything works as expected:

```
interface All {
  OptionalType: {
    name: string
  }
}

type OptionalTypeInline = All extends {
  OptionalType: unknown
}
  ? All["OptionalType"]
  : never

// Do something with OptionalType
```

You can also check or tweak [this example demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/importing-a-type-if-defined-forked-xkfjtd?file=/index.ts).

### Update

There was a problem in the accepted solution, which I marked out in my first comment to it. However, later I worked around that problem further in my code. You see, I used that OptionalType (which is really CustomEvents) in a "loop", and I managed to rewrite it to something like this:

```
[K in keyof Events]: (
    e: Events[K] extends keyof all.CustomEvents
        ? TargetedEvent<Component> & { detail: all.CustomEvents[Events[K]] }
        : TargetedEvent<Component>
) => void
```

Sorry for not sharing all the details in the question from the very beginning.

Comment: When you define it inline it should be using a namespace, not an interface.

Comment: @caTS, that is a legitimate remark, thank you. What I really need is to use the imported type, inlining was for testing purposes only.

Comment: Do you have a reason to do this? Seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me...

Comment: The goal is to provide Preact type definitions for the custom events' `detail` property for those components who are using that property and thus defining its type under the optional type declaration. Note, not all the components have custom events with `detail`, hence they don't need to define its interface.

Comment: @caTS, also, the files with Preact type definitions are generated automatically, so I can't manually import or skip importing the type when it is missing for each component individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't know if this is what you want, but you can use [ambient modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) in combination with [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) to check if a type exists in a module:

```js
import * as all from "./types";

// This declares that there is an interface 'OptionalType' in "./types"
// If OptionalType does NOT exist in "./types" it will be declared as {}
// If OptionalType does exist in "./types" our declaration will be merged and it will have the type { name: string; }
declare module "./types" {
  interface OptionalType {
  }
}

// Here we check if it has the name attribute to know wether it was the declaration by us or the merged declaration.
type OptionalTypeConditional = all.OptionalType extends {
  name: string
} ? all.OptionalType
  : never;
```

In my testing this only works, if there is at least one other type in `./types`. Otherwise it is not recognized as a module if it is completely empty.

Comment: That's a good idea. Thank you. Alas, I don't know the shape of `OptionalType`, it is completely free form and depends on the actual component. The `{name: string}` type was just one example. In my lib, a component may define a map of event names to `event.detail` types, both of them arbitrary. The only thing I can be sure about, is that event names all have the same prefix.

I thought I could work around this by checking if `OptionalType` is empty: `type OptionalType= all.OptionalType extends Record<string, never> ? never : all.OptionalType`. But that didn't work with interface.

Comment: I worked around the problem in the previous comment further in my code. You see, I used that `OptionalType` (which is really `CustomEvents`) in a "loop", and I managed to rewrite it (see the update in the question for the code).
So, your answer actually solved my problem. Thank you. And sorry for not sharing all the details in the question.

Comment: I also tried to make it work with detecting the empty interface but couldn't. I hoped, that you had some common property on `OptionalType` that you could use. I'm happy you found a solution for your use-case.

Answer (score -3):

```ts
import { OptionalType } from './my-component';

// ...
```

You can import exported members of a module by encasing them in curly braces.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem - OP wants to "conditionally import" something.

Comment: Since `OptionalType` is optional, this will produce an error if `my-component` does not define it.